# Wifi does'nt work on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, internet

I have RTL8723BE network card and 3.19 kernel. The Wifi was working really really slow uptil now, frequently disconnecting and I had to reconnect again after certain time, Now it has completely stopped working. Wifi network shows up in the list and is also connected successfully, but internet doesn't work. Everything works fine on Windows (I have a dual booted machine).

I've tried every solution on internet, I've installed the latest drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ and also used `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` but nothing changed. It connects to the network but internet doesn't work.

Edit1 : My Bluetooth is also not working, it scans the network but doesn't show up any devices. Also, my laptop is discoverable still other devices like my phone and other laptop doesn't detect it.

Iptables :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: If the wifi gets connected, but you still can't connect to internet, it could mean that a firewall is blocking you. Can you paste the output of `sudo iptables -L` ?

Comment: @PrahladYeri its `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source       destination`  `Chain FORWARD(policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source       destination`  `Chain OUTPUT(policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source       destination`

Comment: Okay, your firewall is clear, maybe the issue is with the access-point (Your router or Access-point from where you are getting the internet), have you ruled out any ISP issues?. Also, add the `iptables` output as an edit to your answer, not a comment.

Comment: @PrahladYeri actually I cant access internet through my laptop so I had to type it through phone. Anyways, my Wifi started working again out of the blue, and Iam sure it will stop again pretty soon. This keeps on happening idk why :-/

Comment: This is not a firewall issue. It's difficult to troubleshoot without more info. When the wifi stops working check the last few entries of a couple relevant log files in /var/log/ like dmesg, messages, syslog etc. to see if there is any info regarding your wifi hardware. My guess is that it is most likely something on your network rather than you ubuntu install, unless the kernel module you loaded isin't working properly, but we need more info from you.